# VB.NET regex searching for AAA-9999

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need help with finding the first 3 capital letters A-Z and then a space followed by 4 numbers 0-9.

```
 Dim IndividualClasses As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(AllExitClasses(a), "([A-Z])([A-Z])([A-Z]) ([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])")
```

An example input string would be `AML 4309` or `DEF 4298`.
The above 7 characters are what I want to get out of string.

Comment: so what's wrong with the above?

Comment: it doesn't work; and this is an example of the total string inside of AllExitClasses(a)     "AFA 4313 AFA 4333 AFA 4335 AFA 4350 AFA 4500 AFA 4502 AFA "

Comment: my goal is to end up with AFA-4313; AFA-4333; AFA-4335; etc

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Since you preprocess your input string, you can use

```
Dim IndividualClasses As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(AllExitClasses(a).Replace(" ", "-"), "[A-Z]{3}[-][0-9]{4}")
```

**REGEX EXPLANATION**:

- `[A-Z]{3}` - 3 occurrences of English letters A to Z
- `[-]` - A character class matching exactly one hyphen
- `[0-9]{4}` - Exactly 4 occurrences of digits from 0 to 9.

Note that I removed capturing groups since you do not seem to be using them at all, and I am using [limiting quantifiers](http://regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit), e.g. `{4}`.

Note that you could use your input string as is and previous regex `[A-Z]{3}\p{Zs}[0-9]{4}`, but you would need to iterate through the match collection and replace a space in each Match.Value with a hyphen creating a new array.

[Here is an IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/dD7RXV)

Comment: Nice, great example and well explained!

Comment: I see that the string you have contains many substrings you are looking to extract. When you say "not working" do you mean you need to extract the substrings *and* replace the space with a hyphen in each match?

Comment: That probably wasnt meant for me ... but the OP I would assume?

Comment: @436f6465786572 Yes, OP. I am on a mobile, and it is really difficult to type your ID :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I replaced the spaces with a dash 
then I am using this Regular expression 
"([A-Z])([A-Z])([A-Z])([-])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])")
which works

```
AllExitClasses(a) = AllExitClasses(a).Replace(" ", "-")

                    '
                    MyClassString = AllExitClasses(a).ToString
                    Dim IndividualClasses As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(MyClassString, "([A-Z])([A-Z])([A-Z])([-])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])")
```

Comment: Please dont add this as an aswer. Put these changes up top please and remove this...

Answer (score -1):

```
Regex.Matches([variable], "^([A-Z]{3,3})(\s)([0-9]{4,4})$")
```

This regex will find your AAA 1111 (3 uppercase letters with `[A-Z]{3,3}`; one white space with `(\s)`; and exactly 4 digits with `([0-9]{4})`). I have found that http://regex101.com helps a lot with expressions in different languages.

Comment: Note that this will only match it if the _entire_ string equals "AML 4309" (or whatever). Assuming the asker wants to match this somewhere in a larger string, you would need to lose the "^" and the "$".

Comment: Please explain to the OP what this does. Just posting code doesnt help **if you dont know what it does...**

Comment: I hope you troll everyone for this. OP--this regex will find your AAA 1111 (3 uppercase letters [A-Z]{3,3} one white space (\s) and exactly 4 digits ([0-9]{4}). This pattern but does not replace the blank space with a dash. I have found that this site: (https://regex101.com/) helps a lot with expressions in different languages.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. This is especially true of regexen, which are notorious for being opaque line noise to most. (This comment is canned, because I see so many answers that need it posted.)